# Execute Query based on the JSON that stored inside the column

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jsonb

I am using PostgresSQL database and I have four columns in a table and one of them stores a JSON, for example:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
```

I want to execute query that returns me all the rows which have c = 3 in that column. How can I achieve this with Hibernate?

Comment: No I am storing datatype as 'JSONB'.

Comment: Why are you saving such values in JSON?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/pires/hibernate-postgres-jsonb

Answer (score 1):

Use [`->>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

```
-- Example data
create table test (id int, js jsonb);
insert into test values 
(1, '{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}'),
(2, '{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"4"}');

--query
select * 
from test
where js->>'c' = '3';

 id |               js               
----+--------------------------------
  1 | {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hey thanks man I have tried this and it got worked. :-)
But now there is another problem.
If i run the query in pgadmin it works fine and gives me output.
but if i run it through code from hibernate it is not working.
anyidea??

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know hibernate. I think however that a professional ORM should be able to perform any correct SQL query acceptable by db server. If there is a problem with it, the mapper is just useless.

Comment: @HardikChauhan check hibernate version, so it's compatible with the latest postgres 9.4 features.

Comment: Hibernate supports *native queries*: [Community Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html), [Hibernate native SQL queries examples](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/), [Hibernate - Native SQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm).