# Querying JSON array from postgresql in hibernate throws No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using PostgreSQL database and having a JSON type column in a table. The JSON value which is stored there in the column is having an iterative section which i do need to be retrieved from the database as an list.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT json_array_elements(table_column_name->'BBList') FROM table_name", nativeQuery = true)
public List <Object[]> findJsonList();
```

And the query returns this error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

What would be the correct return type of this?

([image: see the JSON image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case , try using  `->> operator:`

Please see post below :

[Execute Query based on the JSON that stored inside the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236905/execute-query-based-on-the-json-that-stored-inside-the-column)